# Is this transistor configuration considered "Push-Pull"?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, push-pull

I have read that the output stages of some operational amplifiers use push-pull transistor configurations. I was looking over the datasheet for the [LM741](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) and was wondering if this was one of those instances?

[image]

Q14 and Q20 appear to be connected together in a push-pull manner, but their bases are driven independently, or so it seems.

Comment: Yep, that's a push-pull output and the VBE multiplier formed by the NPN with R7 & R8 makes it class AB.  The bases of Q14 & Q2 are not really being driven independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the term push-pull is mostly used with digital circuits, but this circuit does indeed both source and sink current.

The two transistors are driven by the same signal (collector of q15/q17), but with a small fixed offset (created by the unmarked transistor with the two resistors) to limit the coross-over distrortian (when the output switches from sourcing to sinking).

Comment: "Push Pull" originated with audio output stages, well before transistor logic. In the early 1930s you could get both output devices integrated in the same package... http://www.r-type.org/addtext/add019.htm

Comment: "Push-pull" is a figurative name of a general topology idea that does not depend on the specific implementation (it is even not only an electrical idea). It shows how to build a composite bidirectional (bilateral) source by combining two unidirectional sources - positive (Q14 and V+) and negative (Q20 and V-). Note that "pushing" and "pulling" are created by two different devices that complement each other (thus the other name of this arrangement - "complementary stage"). Also this is the same (half)bridge idea.

Comment: AFAIK a push-pull in TLL chips is made of two NPN transistors - complementatry in purpose, but not in type of device.

Comment: Really the TTL output stage (with another figurative name - "totem pole") is composed by two equal (as a type) but different (as a function) devices - the upper common-collector stage (emitter follower) "pushes" the load, and the lower common-emitter stage "pulls" the load... a pretty ugly configuration...